# ZPL2 - Rotating text changes alignment

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I'm using the ^A command in ZPL2 to print the Q font, and I want it rotated 90 degrees.  I would think this line would print the "00" up against the left edge of the label since the first ^FO parameter is zero:

```
^XA
^PR2
^MD15
^PW1200
^LL590
^LH0,0
^FB500,14,,^FO0,135^AQR,1,1^FD00^FS
^PQ1
^XZ
```

. . . but it's not.  It's indented about a fourth of the way across the label.  Using that same code, I swap out ^AQR with ^AQN and the "00" prints right up against the left edge.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I'm using a GX430t if that makes a difference.  I'm not sure it does since labelary displays it the same way.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Rotation in ZPL is a bit odd.  It does not work like HTML canvas or other modern graphics environments where the size of the drawing surface affects the rotation.

Since you are using labelary, take a look at the following ZPL, which is a simplified version of your example, without the font rotation and label dimensions, and with a box added to show the extent of the `^FB` you defined.  (The font Q line height is ~25 dots : 14x25 == 350.)

```
^XA
^LH0,0
^FPH
^FO0,135^GB500,350^FS
^FB500,14,,^FO0,135^AQ,1,1^FD00^FS
^XZ
```

Now let's add in the font rotation which causes the `^FB` to rotate as well.  Since graphics don't rotate, we will swap the width and height of the `^GB` to show the equivalent rotation of the box:

```
^XA
^LH0,0
^FPH
^FO0,135^GB350,500^FS
^FB500,14,,^FO0,135^AQR,1,1^FD00^FS
^XZ
```

I think you can now see how the rotation worked.  The `^FB` rotates around the `^FO` point.  But there is also some built in x,y translation based on the dimensions of the `^FB`.